# Apache Solr search query when user made a TYPO in text

Tags: solr, solr8.4.1

I have added the data to solr.

Name field values are: "batman","bat man","bat-man"

so if a user searched for "btman" the result should show all the above values in search.

I found the query like: `localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=Name%3Abtman~2`

but it won't work in all cases.

I need suggession for the Solr query which fetch the result with typos and recomendations.

Comment: First - which cases do you expect it to work with and it doesn't? What is the field type of your `Name` field?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should use [Synonym filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-SynonymGraphFilter) in Solr.

You basically need to create a Synonym file and pass it as an input where you think such spelling mistakes would occur.

Answer (score 1):

Solr comes with SpellCheck Compponent. The SpellCheck component is designed to provide inline query suggestions based on other, similar, terms. The basis for these suggestions can be terms in a field in Solr, externally created text files, or fields in other Lucene indexes.

In your case the spellcheck component will help you to achieve the same.

Please refer the solr documentation for configuring the spellcheck component.

[Solr SpellCheck Compenent](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/spell-checking.html)

If you query to the below url :

```
http://localhost:8986/solr/upgrade1/spell?q=retil&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck=on&wt=xml
```

The result page :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?